# Getting an Oulook PST file error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

Having an issue with Microsoft Outlook caused by a 1.9-gig Outlook PST file. Is their a way to allow the file to be bigger or any other options to prevent this error?

[image: Outlook Error]

Answer (score 4):

Outlook versions prior to 2007 don't allow PST file sizes > 2GB. You can upgrade to Outlook 2007/2010 or otherwise you'll have to create a new PST file and use the new one going forward.

Comment: if you dont upgrade, splitting PSTs is the way to go.  Be sure to reduce the size of your PST below 1.9GB as you might still get the occasional error.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your .PST is already corrupted.

I recommend for you to run scanpst.exe, this is just to prevent you from loosing any important folders, in your PST.

[How to repair corrupted Data files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-HA010075831.aspx)